# Using GROUP BY CUBE convert the result to Cross-tabular form

Tags: apex, soql, javascript, json

I have an object named CrmData where I have fields **Number__C(integer), Date__c(date), CrmDefinition__c(master-details)** and snapshot of sample data..

[image]

here I am getting data into a `List result = [SELECT .. FROM Crm__c];
from this output I want a json like below.. key as a CrmDefinition__r.name value as Number__c and date.. for example on date 2018-01-03 there is no Test2. it should have only Test1 and number... there can be many CrmDefinition like Test1, Test2, Test3..

```
{
    "Test1": 12,
    "Test2": 11,
    "date": "2018-01-01"
},
{
    "Test1": 15,
    "Test2": 23,
    "date": "2018-01-02"
},
{
   "Test1": 20,
   "date": "2018-01-03"
}
```

I tried so many ways doing it but I have to use 2 inner loops and when there is more data it throw

> APEX CPU TIME LIMIT

then I found exactly what I want in Salesforce document in below Link..
[GROUP BY CUBE](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_groupby_cube.htm)

[image: I want exactly like this image.. this will easy to convert into JSON.]

I am using lightning component.. if it is possible in javascript then also it will work for me..

Let me know if I have missed something or any extra information you require from me.

Comment: What is your question? You can use `GROUP BY CUBE ` in the Apex controller of a Lightning component.

Comment: my question is who can i use GROUP BY CUBE or anyother method to achieve the JSON given in example... the GROUP BY CUBE method I have added because I saw the example (given in image) is exactly what I want. but I am not sure who can I achieve

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate in javascript controller/helper but it might take time but will not throw APEX CPU Time Limit error.

in your helper method in component.

1. You need to Sort your data by Date. So that you will have the list as sorted by date and then you can iterate over the list and inside that get the Crmdefinition__c one by one and jump to next date..
2. You need to get the List of CrmDefinition__c which are present in you data and store it in attribute called `component.set('v.definitionList', crmdefinitionList);`
3. Create method in helper

   ```
   createJSON : function(component, event, helper) {
      var resultData = result; // list of records
      var jsonDataSet = {}; // map to create jsonData for date wish
      var jsonData = []; // list of data which you can convert into json
      var definitionList = List of CrmDefinition;
      var definitionCount = definitionList.length;
      for(var i=0; i< resultData.length; i=i+definitionCount) {
          if (i !== resultData.length) {
              jsonDataSet['date'] = resultData[i].Date__c;
              for(var j=0; j< definitionList.length; j++){
                  if(resultData[i+j].Crmdefinition__c != '') {
                      jsonDataSet[resultData[i+j].Crmdefinition__c] = resultData[i+j].Number__c;
                  }
              }
              jsonData.push(jsonDataSet);
              jsonDataSet = {};
          }
      }
      return {jsonData: jsonData}
   }
   ```

Use `JSON.Stringify(jsonData)` which will give you exactly what you want.. Test it let me know if it works or not?